# Is the running of electric charge the same as the running of the fine structure constant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, charge, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, physical-constants

This is a simple question - maybe too simple. If I recall correctly, Feynman wrote about the running of the electric charge with energy (or 4-momentum). Nowadays, one hears more about the running of alpha.

Are these two "runnings" one and the same thing or are they different processes?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function_(physics)#Quantum_electrodynamics) regarding their equivalence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) $\alpha \propto e^2$ is proportional to the square of the [elementary charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge) $e$, so their [renormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization) runnings are linked/are the same thing.